# Inter-Processor Interrupts, X86_64 bit CPU ,2.6.32-73 kernel, Ubuntu 10.04, Usage

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I'm trying to use in inter-processor interrupts (IPIs) in Ubuntu server 10.04, with kernel and CPU specified above.

I got lots of info from Google regrading working with IPI's in SMP architectures,
and understood that there are API function for using IPI such as:

send_IPI_mask(),

send_IPI_self( ),

send_IPI_all( ) and etc.

My problem is much more basic i cant find anywhere a documentation of how to write a program that uses this functions.

I don't even now if i should import some libs for using it?

or i just need to write this function in some right manner?

I would much appreciate a full code example, even of the most basic program that uses IPI.

Or some reference to best practices in writing code using kernel modules.
Thanks.

Edit:
Probably i got it all wrong..
i would ask the question differently is there a way i can use the functions mentioned above using system calls?

If i can what library is loading ioctl is the best way?

Or is there faster way to interact with those function?

Comment: What  are you trying to achieve? IPI is already is handled by low-level kernel code, and it provides high level interfaces such as `on_each_cpu()`. Note that question like "provide me example/documentation" can be considered offtopic and being closed.

Comment: I'm trying to send IPI between 2 CPU.
My final purpose is to create 2 programs,
one of which will prime cache utilization and then halt,
while the second program which works on different CPU will send the IPI to the halted program in specific time intervals.

Comment: I understand this. But this sound like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It will also be greate if you provide your attempts to write code.

Answer (score 0):

All i needed to do is to install linux kernel headers.

**sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)**

from there on i could use function like :

smp_call_function_single
or
on_each_cpu

P.S

for whom of you who want to use it keep in mind that IPI interrupt handlers have to be vary quick and cant be block.